# Consul Client refuses connection to Vault server

Tags: hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

I'm trying to create a Vault network backed by Consul cluster of 3 nodes. I have created a cluster of 3 Consul servers and a Consul client has been connected to the cluster. Now I'm trying to connect
a Vault server to Consul client but client always refuse connection.

`2021-12-03T12:59:27.578Z [WARN]  storage migration check error: error="Get \"http://consul_c1:8501/v1/kv/vault/core/migration\": dial tcp 192.168.48.3:8501: connect: connection refused"`

I built all in docker compose. here are my consul server configs:

```
consul_s1.json
{
  "server": true,
  "node_name": "consul_s1",
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bootstrap_expect": 3,
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": ["consul_s2", "consul_s3"],
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "ui": true
}
```

```
consul_s2.json
{
  "server": true,
  "node_name": "consul_s2",
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bootstrap_expect": 3,
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": ["consul_s1", "consul_s3"],
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "ui": true
}
```

```
consul_s3.json
{
  "server": true,
  "node_name": "consul_s3",
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "bootstrap_expect": 3,
  "data_dir": "/consul/data",
  "retry_join": ["consul_s1", "consul_s2"],
  "log_level": "DEBUG",
  "ui": true
}
```

and consul client config is:

```
consul_c1.json
{
  "node_name": "consul_c1",
  "datacenter": "dc1",
  "bind_addr": "0.0.0.0",
  "retry_join": ["consul_s1", "consul_s2", "consul_s3"],
  "data_dir": "/consul/data"
}
```

and configs for vault:

```
vault_s1.json
{
  "backend": {
    "consul": {
      "address": "consul_c1:8501",
      "path": "vault/"
    }
  },
  "listener": {
    "tcp":{
      "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
      "tls_disable": 1
    }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

and here is the docker compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  consul_s1:
    image: consul:1.10.4
    container_name: consul_s1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./consul/consul_s1/config/consul_s1.json:/consul/config/consul_s1.json:ro
    networks:
      - consul
    ports:
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8600:8600/tcp'
      - '8600:8600/udp'
    command: 'agent'

  consul_s2:
    image: consul:1.10.4
    container_name: consul_s2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./consul/consul_s2/config/consul_s2.json:/consul/config/consul_s2.json:ro
    networks:
      - consul
    command: 'agent'

  consul_s3:
    image: consul:1.10.4
    container_name: consul_s3
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./consul/consul_s3/config/consul_s3.json:/consul/config/consul_s3.json:ro
    networks:
      - consul
    command: 'agent'

  consul_c1:
    image: consul:1.10.4
    container_name: consul_c1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8501:8500
    volumes:
      - ./consul/consul_c1/config/consul_c1.json:/consul/config/consul_c1.json:ro
    networks:
      - consul
    command: 'agent'

  vault:
    image: vault:latest
    container_name: vault_s1
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    volumes:
      - ./vault/vault_s1/config/vault_s1.json:/vault/config/vault_s1.json
      - ./vault/vault_s1/policies:/vault/policies
      - ./vault/vault_s1/data:/vault/data
      - ./vault/vault_s1/logs:/vault/logs
    environment:
      - VAULT_ADDR=http://127.0.0.1:8200
    networks:
      - consul
    command: server -config=/vault/config/vault_s1.json
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    depends_on:
      - consul_s1

networks:
  consul:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the "client_addr" configuration on the Consul client. By default it is localhost. The HTTP interface will use this address, and if it's listening only on localhost, then Vault may not be able to communicate with the client, as you have Vault configured to reach out to it on a different network interface.

https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options#_client

Comment: I added "client_addr": "0.0.0.0" but still it refuses connection

Comment: Can you also update the Consul address in your Vault configuration to use port 8500 instead of 8501?

Comment: I cannot expose 8500 for consul client as consul_s1 has occupied it

Comment: I'd recommend not deploying a Consul client on the same node as a Consul server. By doing that, you could also have this port freed up and it may work with that configuration.

Nonetheless, I would recommend deploying your Consul client c1 on the same host as your Vault server, and then configure Vault's Consul address as 127.0.0.1:8500.